# All apps scripts fail with error INTERNAL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-apps-script-editor, google-admin-settings-api

I have a client that I've written a custom apps script for. Every time I execute it from his account (just like any other script) there is this error:

We're sorry, there was an unexpected error while creating the Cloud Platform project. Error code INTERNAL.

Executing the script from any other account works perfectly, including free ones.

I've checked their Google Admin setting, the Cloud Platform is on. It might be worth mentioning they have legacy G Suite Free.

I'd be super grateful for any help as I'm out of ideas already.

Comment: What is the code doing? [There's not much you can do about INTERNAL errors](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors#handling_errors). I would suggest contacting G Suite support in this case, but there's nothing that users here will be able to do for you.

Comment: The code in question create a draft with a quote based on the Google Sheet data. But in reality ALL scripts fail under the client's account, even if something like function foo() { return; } fails.

Funnily enough G Suite support sent me here. I've tried them, I've tried Google community support and I've tried a lot of stuff in the admin panel. Nothing works so far.

Comment: Is the client signed into two accounts at the same time? Also is the behaviour replicable in private/incognito mode?

Comment: The 2 accounts was a good idea, tried being signed in to one account only but it didn't help. Not sure how the incognito mode will help, the script needs authorization and access to GDocs and GMail t run

Comment: If only one account being signed in doesn't fix this, and not even `function foo() { return; }` will run, then I urge you to contact G Suite support again, give them all the information here and explain that this is an account specific issue which users of Stackoverflow can not help you with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I re-opened the ticket with Google Support.