# GSuite support not helpful: “We're sorry, there was an unexpected error while creating the Cloud Platform project. Error code INTERNAL. “

Tags: google-apps-script

I am facing the same issue as this post here:
[All apps scripts fail with error INTERNAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068990/all-apps-scripts-fail-with-error-internal)

I have contacted Google Support but after a few rounds of Q&A and sending videos they haven't been able to help me solve it yet. In the meantime, have people had such issues and had Google help solve their issues?

If so could you share how they solved it so I can make suggestions to Google support on potential solutions?

Comment: Can you blur any personal info from your videos and make them public?

Answer (score 0):

The [error code](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors#handling_errors) `INTERNAL` signals an enclosed issue that may be originated by a bug. I strongly recommend you to contact [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) in order to receive customized help.